How can agriculture/industry be economically viable in setting where magic exists?
D&D type setting where creation of materials from 'thin air' with some sort of ingredients. Basic economics would state that anything made with little to no initial cost would drive prices way down. Question is how can farming/industry/any production be viable craft in such a setting?

Can everyone use magic? Does magic require special skills that can/need to be specialized?

@JuimyTheHyena Anyone can, but effectiveness is up to 'talent'. However, learning the basics takes years of study.

What's the average life expectancy?

We don't answer questions where the poster comes with a list of answers and expect to get more. Read our [help].

@L.Dutch 3 is too much?

You have a problem and have already solutions. There is nothing for us to do.

(1) "With a list of ingredients". Ingredients have a cost. (2) The question does not say how long it takes for a magic user to create a kilogram of wheat. For example, a farming family farming 5 hectares can make (with medieval technology) about 15,000 kg of wheat per year, or about 40 kg of wheat per day, or about 1.7 kg of wheat per hour. (3) The question does not say anything about transportation and distribution costs. All in all, mushrooms and berries are free to take in the forest, but when you buy them in the market they cost money.

Reading your comments and twixt the lines seems you already know the answer, or should. magic is rarely 'free' if and what the spell components and time to cast (including rest and memorization time in whatever version of that game system you use) are and the numbers able to use it are all significant factors, as is do they have something better to do with that time and effort (other spells to memorise & cast worth more to them for financial or personal reasons) .. and you already seem to have shown you're aware of all this.

Can't speak to the crap the current IP owners churn out but in anything but the most imbalanced of monty haul high fantasy campaigns spellcasters in OD&D and AD&D (PC spellcasters aside) in the general population were normally too rare (and demand for their services for other things too high for them to have time to waste on such things) for this to even be a plausible issue worthy of debate.

Magic and teaching might be free, but education never is. It always costs. We always pay a "tuition" to learn. That "tuition" can be in the form of money, time, effort, mistakes, lost opportunities, and constrained knowledge. There are always new things to learn, new crops, new ways to cook so that what is free is not valued. The stuff someone grows / collects will always find a market.

We can create also benzene from air by solar panels, but we do not do it. The cost would be astronomical. Rather we mine the crude oil, refine it and then burn it.

What version of DnD? Because if you read the spell descriptions of the more recent editions there are exactly zero spells that create any permanent material except water.

Good worldbuilding means balancing your magic system
The son of some friends of mine once asked me to evaluate a Star Trek-based Federation space ship they'd created. As is common with 9-11 year olds, the ship was ridiculously overpowered, overarmored, and was brought into existence without even a thought toward economics (what 9-11 year old thinks about economics?). I told him it was a cool ship, but he'd get bored with it quickly. "No way!" he claimed, and off he went.
Not even a week later he and his friends were bored to death with it. The design lacked a simple reality that made it fun to play with — weaknesses. No design is perfect. Energy is not infinite. Armor acts against agility. And things cost! I explained all this to him and he spent months having fun developing space ships that could be beaten.
Godlike powers, like godlike characters, are boring
Which brings me to a basic axiom of worldbuilding: godlike things are boring. Questions asking "how do I defeat my godlike character" appear regularly on this site and they all have the same answer: you can't unless you introduce a weakness.
So... what's the weakness in your magic system? Here are some possibilities...

You have magic that easily brings an abundance of food into reality. This is the agricultural version of a perpetual motion machine (or, if applied to firewood, it's literally a perpetual motion machine), but let's ignore that. In this case your society has no agricultural sector beyond weird people who insist on natural purity, religious fanatics who think magic is evil, and the occasional person born without magic. That's OK! Everybody simply focuses their attention onto something else, like manufacturing. I suspect you'll quickly discover this is an endless rabbit hole ("yeah, but can't they just apply the magic to industry?") that leads to lazy indolence with only an occasional person actualy caring to spend more time better understanding magic. In short, if you take this too far, it gets really boring really quickly.

Or, you can't have a perpetual motion machine. Your magic system requires the consumption of mass equal to the mass being created. Whether you're waving your Harry Potter-esque wand and making a whole meal simply appear or something a bit more sensible like encouraging the growth of a field of wheat or simply curing the field of disease... the material price in terms of mixed (and lost) ingredients is never cheaper than the result. If you're thinking to yourself, "that's just basic college economics!" you're on the right track.

Or you can do something like make using magic painful. As the saying goes, "no pain, no gain!" You want to feed your children? You'll be in bed recovering for a week. You want to feed your neighborhood? You'd better be prepared to die for them because the amount of pain will kill you.

Or you can limit the expression of magic. This is the "Mana" concept where the capacity to perform magic is limited and you can never solve the whole problem (no perpetual motion machine!) before the mana runs out. Of course, you can represent Mana in many ways, such as a recharge time before the mage can perform more magic or by representing it as a rare resource (fairy dust!) that's difficult to obtain and is never available in great quantities (who, then, would use it for something as mundane as agriculture?).


In all of these cases there's a limitation. So when you ask, "how can agriculture be viable" the answer really should be, "there shouldn't be a problem with agriculture in the first place. If there is, you have a badly balanced magic system."
One more thing, you start your post by saying "D&D type setting where creation of materials from 'thin air' with some sort of ingredients." That's not creating materials out of thin air. That's trading one set of resources for another, making mages little different from fantasy industrialists with all the supply chain problems industry has. Just how many ingredients can your mage carry? If the spell requires acolytes holding candles at the points of a pentagram, are they getting paid? Right! Now your mage is a small business owner that needs to provide basic health care and a living wage....

Economics Occurs At The Margin
Depending on the particulars, which you don't provide so I'm speaking in general terms here, all such a magic system does is change the relative scarcity/abundance of certain things.
You say:

...with some sort of ingredients.

So now we know that magic use creates demand for those ingredients. Even if magic itself can generate those ingredients from other ingredients, the end result is the same: the magic you describe does not produce something from nothing (and even if it did, you're still consuming that ever-scarce resource: time), and so even if magic is the most efficient means to generate X, that it requires Y causes demand to shift towards Y proportionate to the efficient quantity where Y converts to X.  Society will then organize itself around the most efficient means to produce sufficient Y.
Eventually you reach a scarcity equilibrium that's a function of one or more of:

The maximum practical rate at which Y can be converted to X by the available subpopulation that can perform (is ready, able, and willing) the magic.

The maximum practical rate at which Y can be produced.

The relative costs of transportation of X and Y.


#1 is your bandwidth for magical production of X, as people learn to perform that magic, it expands (lowering the global rate of the magical resource process) - as people who know how to do it discover better uses of their time, or retire from professional magic use, it contracts.
#2 is your true economic chokepoint. As demand for X (and therefore Y) increases, AND as demand for Y increases as a function of expansion of #1, Y becomes scarcer in the short-run, forcing a higher price until more people are induced to enter Y production.
#3 is the sneaky one. Depending on what Y is, it may be cheaper/easier/more desirable to produce X locally than to acquire Y and send it to someone who can perform the magic.
The pattern this creates is geography dependent: Areas of relative scarcity of Y will have more local production of X. Areas rich in Y will simply use that local abundance to attract converters of Y to X in order to satisfy their demand for X. They will export surplus Y for various other things.
Magic does not invalidate economics, it is simply a competing means of production. It is constrained in exactly the same way as any other process, and markets adapt to those effects and constraints.

Take a look at today. How many people, on average, are farmers? It takes very few people to produce the food everyone eats because our technology expedites everything. I imagine that a fantasy society that can produce food from nowhere would have a similar situation. Very few people would produce food, and everyone else would use that food to further their own purposes. Which means, rather than drive prices down, I think this kind of creation would lead to a much higher density of artisan workers.
If this kind of magic is brand new, then certainly conjured food and materials would drive prices down. But long-term I think everything would balance out.
As for farming itself, I don't think it would be as viable, as you say. But there's probably a solid number of people who'd prefer "organic" food and the like, causing real-grown food to become a commodity. Like heirloom tomatoes, but for things as everyday as eggs. Or, since this is D&D, you could easily invent a group of Luddites who oppose magical conjuration because its putting them out of a job.

There are several ways around this

Spells require material components, which require agriculture/industry. If you want to cast a spell you need to buy, make, or farm crops, textiles, etc.
Magic has a cost. Either it takes vitality or sanity from the caster. It might be reasonable to use magic to eat when you would die otherwise, but if it will drive you mad or take years off your life, you wouldn't do it unless you have to.
Magic is rare. If only 1 in 10,000 people can use magic, they might have a good career in using magic to make food and other things, but if they can only produce a few hundred pounds of food per day, they can't be the only source of food.
Magic has limitations. Maybe only the creator of the food can eat it, if others try it turns to air. Maybe magic can't be used to make food, or the food doesn't actually provide nourishment.

